# R: test on multiple versions

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, configuration

Does anyone have a solution for automating unit testing of R packages under various multiple versions of R and/or prerequisite packages?

Python has a nice package, [`tox`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which allows the user to write a configuration file specifying what dimensions to expand over, then it runs testing under all combinations of those.

Comment: [r-hub](https://github.com/r-hub/rhub) might be what you're after?

Comment: maybe take a look at `testthat`

Comment: @SymbolixAU I think that would be a good option for open source work, but this is for proprietary packages we wouldn’t want going to an external service.

Comment: @Shree I don’t think `testthat` has that functionality.